# What does it mean when Ubuntu software updater shows an item available but is unselected?

Tags: grub2, updates, 22.04

Today there were 2 updates available, but for some reason the GRUB update was set so that it was not selected (see image).

What is that indicating?
It is attempting to let me know that the update is not compatible with my configuration or machine?

Or something else?

[image: ubuntu upgrade item unselected]

Also, I just ran the Software Updater again to see if it would show the GRUB item again and instead it just showed the following message:

[image: all software is updated]

Does that mean it actually did install the item even though I didn't select it?  This seems a bit odd.

Comment: This is a new feature of Ubuntu. Updates are installed in a staggered manner. So that they can be stopped if problems are reported. The unchecked updates will automatically be checked and be available in a few days.

Comment: Sure that does answer my first question -- however, I would've never connected "phased updates" to my question and couldn't have really known that term ahead of time.  It makes a bit difficult to search for.  
Also, why did mine show up as if it had installed it when I ran the software updater immediately again?  The GRUB item no longer showed up.  Did it actually install GRUB even though I didn't select it?  I'm not sure.

Comment: Actually as I read the other answer I kind of don't think it does answer my question because mine shows the User Interface & the other one talks so explicitly about the apt cmd line interface.  This could still be a separate question related to unselected items in the software updater.  It doesn't matter though.  But I'm guessing that the snapshot will be relevant to future readers.

Comment: The GUI "software Updates" started doing the phased update sometime in 20,04, I think. In those days the `apt` command ignored the phased update. That changed with 22.04. You can use the command `sudo apt update` and the `apt list --upgradable` to check if Grub was updated or if it is still pending. You can also check the file `/var/log/dpkg.log` to see what exactly was updated and when.

Comment: That's a good answer and would make a good answer to my question.  